# Как найти центр объекта?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как найти и поставить объект в центр другого объекта (Button в PictureBox)? Использую WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вычислить центр PictureBox  (Width/2, Height/2)
2. Поставить Button в центр PictureBox  (Width/2, Height/2). это `Button.Location = new Point(PictureBox.Width/2 - Button.Width/2, PictureBox.Height/2 - Button.Height/2)`

Как то так думаю

Comment: Ваш способ к сожалению не работает. :-(

Comment: у вас парент Button PickureBox или Form?

Comment: У меня парент Form

Comment: ну тогда нужно считать относительно Form